# Returning IEnumerable with using

Tags: .net, delegates, using-statement, deferred-execution

Interesting problem I ran across which makes total sense.  I have a generic method like so:

```
public TResult Run<TResult>(Func<SqlDataReader, TResult> resultDelegate)
{
   TResult result;

   using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) // command is SqlCommand with attached SqlConnection
   {
      result = resultsDelegate(reader);
   }

   // Some other unrelated code (but that's why result has a variable)

   return result;
}
```

In one case, the `resultDelegate`'s return type (`TResult`) is `IEnumerable<object>`.  The problem is that the `Run` function returns immediately due to deferred execution, disposing the SqlDataReader.  Later in the code when I try to read through the results (which the delegate does `reader.Read()`, I get an `InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.`

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way around this.  I know I can return a concrete list, but I would like to avoid that if possible.  I can also move the using statement inside the delegate, but once again, if I can avoid doing that for every delegate it would be nice.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
public TResult Run<TResult>(Func<SqlDataReader, TResult> resultDelegate)
{
   TResult result;

   using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) // command is SqlCommand with attached SqlConnection
   {
      result = resultsDelegate(reader);
      if (typeof(TResult) == typeof(IEnumerable<object>)) 
      {
         var enumerable = result as IEnumerable<object>;
         if (enumerable != null) 
         {
            result = enumerable.ToList();  
         }
      }
   }

   // Some other unrelated code (but that's why result has a variable)

   return result;

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea--you're forcing it to be a concrete list, but outside the scope of the delegate.  I think in this case it has hidden and unintended consequences (list has to be allocated in memory).  If I had to go this route I would probably throw an exception instead if the delegate returns IEnumerable; that way it's obvious what is really occurring.

Comment: kudos JeffN825 for a very creative answer.

Comment: If you don't keep your reader open, there's no way of using deferred execution at all. You MUST allocate and enumerate the results in the scope of the reader.

Comment: Right, I understand it *must* be allocated.  What I meant is I would rather do the allocating somewhere else in the code where it's more explicit and obvious.  This can easily hide the fact that it has been allocated.